# NSTableview and calculation of attributes

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nstableview

Can anyone please help me with the following problem?

I'm creating an application which holds the entity, called a salt.
This entity has some attributes like milligram and millmolar (concentrations).

They can be calculated by this formula milligram/molar mass (constant) = millimolar.
I have a tableview which has the colums for these attributes, and I would like the application to calculate one, if the other is filled in, or changed.

I'm trying to use `- (void)tableViewSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)aNotification` but I can't seem to make it work.

Comment: Did you forget to paste part of your code?

Comment: Trying to do something like this:  (void)tableViewSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)aNotification{
 NSNumber *ZnSO47H2Omm;
 ZnSO47H2Omm = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithDouble:287.53];
 
 Macro.milligram = Macro.millimolar * ZnSO47H2Omm;

Answer (score -1):

I've put [a demo project](https://github.com/natechan/ConversionTableViewDemo) up on GitHub that does what you're describing.  This project utilizes [bindings](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/cocoabindings/cocoabindings.html), the [`NSArrayController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSArrayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class, and [Registering Dependent Keys](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVODependentKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002179-SW2) via `keyPathsForValuesAffecting<Key>` for [Key-Value Observing](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html).

In the demo, after you edit the value in one column of the table, the value in the other column is altered too via the conversion factors.  It shouldn't be too bad to adapt the relevant parts of this demo project to your salt conversion table view scenario.

Comment: Thanks for sharing Nate, this is surely going to be very useful!!

Comment: @Bassie Glad it was helpful; hope it answers your question.

Comment: I'm moving on step by step.

Comment: I can't seem to open the xib file in your example.

Comment: Any idea? maybe an old version of xcode (3.2.6) or do I need some plugins

Comment: You'll need a newer version of Xcode (the latest is 4.6) to open the xib.

Comment: The demo project is gone.